# Global Page Success / Warning / Error Messages not showing in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, session, magento-2.2.5, global-messages

None of the global page messages are appearing on any page in the admin panel. This includes and is not limited to my own custom messages, saving a product, canceling an order and clearing the cache.

I've tried with all caches enabled and disabled with no luck.

Some investigation has shown that I can get messages showing by adding `$clear = false;` in the `getMessages()` function in `vendor/magento/framework/Message/Manager.php` on line 120. This tells me that messages are being cleared on every redirect without allowing the latest added message to display.

I can't tell what happened to the system before I started seeing this bug.